# Google Authenticator after an iphone motherboard replacement

Tags: iphone, google, motherboard

A little while back my iPhone X started having motherboard issues and was unable to be booted up.

I was using Google Authenticator to store many accounts, some of which may be impossible to get to without those codes.

From what I understand **Google Authenticator is tied to your hardware**, and as a result when I restored my icloud backup to a new phone, the Google Authenticator keys are lost.

This leaves me no choice but to try to get the old iPhone working so I can safely restore an iCloud backup to it and have the google authenticator codes appear again. If it’s the same phone this will work fine.

The question is:

If the phones motherboard is replaced, does that effectively change the hardware so much that google authenticator won’t recognize it as being the same phone?

Comment: Short answer to your question is "yes" it changes it.  Full answer is in the dupe.

Comment: These answers all say that the keys will restore successfully if restored to the same device, even if that device has been wiped clean and then restored via iCloud backup. I can confirm from experience this behaviour works. But what is it about the device that allows the restore to work? And will changing the motherboard affect that?

Comment: Changing the motherboard means you have a different device.  The authenticator app identifies the hardware by some unique number - a serial number of a chip like the CPU, the MAC address of the WiFi or BT radios, a H/W UUID, anything.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense. Is there any way to know or is it written somewhere what unique number is checked by google authenticator?

Comment: Not that I have seen which is why it such a secure technology.  If you knew what they were using, you could find a way to spoof it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator stores your accounts in the iOS Keychain. There's nothing special about the way this is done - it is the same as with other apps on the iPhone.

When you restore an unencrypted backup, these types of Keychain entries are not included in the backup - and thus cannot be restored. It does not matter if it is restored to the same "motherboard".

If you instead make an encrypted backup (including iCloud backup) and restore from that, your Keychain entries will be restored - and thus your Google Authenticator accounts.

This is entirely intentional from Google, and they have set up the app exactly to do this. If it weren't setup that way, your accounts could be compromised without having the "second factor protection".

The mechanism through which the backup is “linked” to the actual device is entirely implemented by Apple - there’s nothing Google Authenticator-specific about it. The data is encrypted using the Secure Enclave’s unique is as part of the encryption key. The Secure Enclave is a special component of the processor on the iPhone that allows, amongst other things, encryption/decryption of data based on a unique ID that cannot leave the Secure Enclave.

This means that it is not possible to just read out the unique id to perform the decryption somewhere else. In practice this means that the data can only be restored on that physical device (I.e. the device having the same Secure Enclave as when the backup was made).

I know it is too late for you now, but when setting up 2FA accounts, you really want to set up at least 2 devices, so that you have a backup device in case one is lost for any reason.

If the services you use do not support having multiple 2FA codes, I would suggest instead using a different Authenticator app that allow syncing the secret behind the 2FA code between devices. The free Authy app from Twilio is a very popular choice.

Comment: This makes sense but if you restore an iCloud backup to the same phone, the google authenticator keys are successfully restored and work fine, even though the backup is iCloud/unencrypted. So question of whether the same thing will happen if motherboard is changed is still unanswered here

Comment: It’s not using any ids like CPU serial numbers or Bluetooth MAC addresses like described in other comments. It’s just plain Keychain using the Secure Enclave. How have you actually verified that the iCloud backup restored the accounts? It’s definitely not supposed to be doing that, and it would indicate a security problem.

Comment: Hey - it is well known that restoring an iCloud backup to a clean device will restore keys in google authenticator. I’ve done this a few times. It’s only when you restore to a different device that the keys are blank.

Comment: Just checked again and found that Google changed their Authenticator settings in later versions to allow restoring from encrypted iCloud Backups - contrary to what they document on their wiki. It doesn’t really change anything in terms of this question though - the data is protected in exactly the same way, and you cannot restore it to a different device for the same reason.